# Как отловить статус с сервера, в Unity?

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, сервер

Нужно понять какой статус мне возвращает сервер. Например если статус: 201, то регистрация успешна и т.д.

Comment: Из вашего описания совсем не понятно чего вы хотите. Какой сервис, какой статус, что вы используете

Comment: Посылаю http запросы. На сервер посылаю данные регистрации, а в ответ получаю статус либо 400 "bad request"... Либо "201 created"... Вот как отловить статус? И такая же херня, когда Использую socket.io для юнити... Тоже не могу понять как отловить респонс? Риквест посылаю, всё хорошо. А как отловить фидбэк?

Comment: какой метод используете для отправки запроса?

Comment: www - с начала заполняю форму, потом отправляю на сервер. При успешном логине, оно возвращает мне токен, как и написано на сервере. И когда не правильный запрос на регистрацию, оно тоже возвращает мне статус ошибки. А вот когда регистрация успешна... Ничего не происходит. В базу внесено, но как мне в юнити это отловить?

Comment: ну, либо сделать так, чтобы сервер таки отвечал) либо ждите какое-то время и пытайтесь залогиниться автоматом с теми же данными